# Call UI uiObjectInfoApi dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components

[`uiObjectInfoApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) is quite nice in LWC but is there any way it work based on attribute; so that its more dynamic.

Scenario: Object API name is passed from parent to child component which uses it to make a describe call.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class RecordFormWithRecordType extends LightningElement {

    // value to objectName is passed from parent component
    @api objectName;
    @track objectInfo;

    // make describe call dynamically based on objectName
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: objectName }) objectInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

> The only case that requires strings instead of imported objects and fields is if a component isn’t aware of which object it’s using. If the component is dynamic at run time, use  `@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'Account' })` to return the object’s fields.

Further the section *Mark a Configuration Object Property as Dynamic and Reactive* mentions:

> In the wire adapter’s configuration object, prefix a value with `$` to reference a property of the component instance. The `$` prefix tells the wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as `this.propertyName`. The property is reactive. If the property’s value changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders.

---

So using the property name as below, should work:

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectName' }) objectInfo;
```

Comment: Awesome @Jayant, thanks for your help!