# LWC call uiObjectInfoApi Imperatively

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my LWC, I want to call a method from `uiObjectInfoApi`
Something I have in LWC file:

```
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

and a method definition like:

```
async lwcGetObjectInfo(objectName) {
    return getObjectInfo(objectName);
}
```

somewhere in my code, I will call to the method `lwcGetObjectInfo` but it's always failed with error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[this.callback is not a function]
```

I don't want to use @wire service since my code may need to be called very dynamically from many places. That's why I want to call it imperatively (which we [are able to do with Apex method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative)). Is there anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need to use the standard platform wire methods as wire methods. You can't use them imperatively. I created a mildly complicated system to work around this problem involving a common component that loads all this data once, and all components could just read this data as needed.

```
export default class CommonComponent extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT }) accountDescribe;
}
```

...

```
export default class MyChildComponent extends CommonComponent {
  someMethod() {
    const fields = this.accountDescribe.data.fields;
    // we can do something with the account fields here
  }
}
```

Just remember that the describe information won't necessarily be available in connectedCallback, render, or renderedCallback on the first render cycle, so you may need to use async/await to wait for the data:

```
async connectedCallback() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  const fields = this.accountDescribe.data.fields;
  // we can do something here with the describe data
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I am not sure I can follow your workaround. To be correct, I think my problem is exactly call uiObjectInfoApi dynamically. I have read: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256584 I can imagine something like: wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectName' }) lwcGetObjInfo; Whenever I want to change config obj of wire, I can change the $objectName value. The problem is I don't get the your point at: await Promise.resolve(); I understand that you want to wait for the wire service data ready before getting it out right? await Promise.resolve(); is pseudo code only?

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 It's literal code. That line of code allows a render cycle to pass before continuing. However, that may not be enough. You might want to think about using a pubpub (see [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub)) to communicate between a single component that handles describes dynamically.